# JS expand onClick multiple events

Tags: javascript, html

Please check this page first : [Solarking - About Us](http://www.solarkingindia.com/about-us/)

Check first 2 boxes which has a READ MORE button. On clicking them, they expand a paragraph.

Now I want it to be like when I click on it, it should expand the text and change the button value to "CLOSE" from "READ MORE". And on again clicking on "CLOSE", it should change value to "READ MORE".

I searched for long time to see how to fire multiple events on `onClick`, but I saw that some said to use a `;` in them, some said make a new function and put 2 functions in it.

Now I tried to make a new function with 2 functions inside it (one to expand the paragraph, other to change value of button, but I failed. (I am new to JS).

Help please. Thank you in advance!
Code I have on the page :

button code:

```
<p style="text-align: right;"><input id="button12" style="background-color: #eca200; color: #ffffff;" onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" type="button" value="Read more" /></p>
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to set a boolean variable.  In other words, let's say that it starts off with the dclaration at the beginning of the page.

```
var hasbeenclicked = false;
```

Then, after the first click

```
hasbeenclicked = true;
```

After a second click

```
hasbeenclicked = false;
```

When the function is called, it checks the variable and operates accordingly. The following is not real JS....

```
if hasbeenclicked = true {

  do some stuff;
```

}

else {

```
  do some other stuff;
```

}

That is a simple way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Additional info:

Use two DIV tags with separate ID's.  One for the paragraph and one for the "label".  Use getelementbyID to alter each one appropriately.

Comment: Oh.. Though I am new to JS, i'll search over web and try to make the complete code and will report back! :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are using jQuery.

You could use a toggle method.

Alter the html link. Add a class of `expander` and use the `data` attribute to identify the paragraph `id`

```
   <p style="text-align: right;">
       <input id="button12" data-toggle="para1" class="expander" style="background-color: #eca200; color: #ffffff;" type="button" value="Read more" />
   </p>
```

The JS

```
    $(".expander").click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        $("#" + self.data('toggle')).slideToggle(500, function () {
            if ($("#" + self.data('toggle')).is(':visible')) { // paragraph is open
                self.val("Close");
            } else { // paragraph is closed
                self.val("Read More");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for responding! :)
Sorry for my newbieness, do I have to add the JS code in <script type="text/javascript"> tag? And are there any changes I have to do in the code you gave? Or just putting it on the page would do?

Comment: @ShubhamRajdhar Yes the JS would have to go in the `script` tag. As long as you have ammended to html to match my example it should work. Each Toggle button will need the `data-toggle` attribute to equal the id of the paragraph you want to open.