# multiple variables for onclick JS event and removing need to double click event handler

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple sections that I am trying to have expand/collapse as the user wants.  Ideally they would be able to have what ever they want open.  I am very new to Javascript, so I don't know if there is a better way to do this.... currently I have a function for each section.  Also, you have to click on the event handler to focus it, then click it again so that it activates the onClick action.  I would like to only have to click the button once for it to do something.

I have looked at [Onclick event only works on double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270540/onclick-event-only-works-on-double-click)  but am not using ajax.
This [JS expand onClick multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050044/js-expand-onclick-multiple-events) did not work.
I also tried this  [javascript - button needs to be click twice for onclick to trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636285/javascript-button-needs-to-be-click-twice-for-onclick-to-trigger)  but I don't think this applies to what I am doing.

```
function ShowMe() {  
var button = document.getElementById("DATA-PERSONAL"); 

var x = document.getElementById("PERSONAL-DATA"); 
 if (x.style.display === "none") 
  {
    button.innerHTML = "-";
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "+"
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 >Personal Data <button onclick="ShowMe()" id="DATA-PERSONAL">+</button></h2>
<div id="PERSONAL-DATA">
  <p> The stuff being hidden/revealed</p>
</div>
```

I expect click on the + once and it will spill the div.  I have to click on the + twice to do this, but after I click on it once it will work again even if I click on something else.  Also, I expect that there is an easier way to script all of the showme() functions to have multiple variables?  Maybe not, currently this page has 27 showme functions.  If that's how it is that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a simple accordion.  You can find any number already made for you using simple jQuery or JS around the web.  But this little tutorial should get you start.

[How to create an accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp).

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there had to be an easier way to do this.  That worked.  Thank you!